# Full Outer Join based off multiple fields

Tags: sql, t-sql, full-outer-join

Here is the situation that I'm facing:

I have two tables A and B.  If records are in table A and not in table B they need to be added to table B.  If records are in table B and not in table A, then they need to be removed out of table B.  The trick here is that it is the mixture of two keys that makes the unique combination

```
Table A    
Operation_Key    Part_Key  
1                1
1                2
2                1
2                3

Table B
Operation_Key    Part_Key  Record_Key
1                1         1
2                1         2
2                3         3
2                4         4
```

I am trying to get the right type of query so that the results returned look like

```
Results
Operation_Key        Part_Key  Record_Key   Action
1                    2         NULL         Add
2                    4         4            Delete
```

The query I have so far looks like similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Action_Table
(
  Action VARCHAR(6),
  Action_Bit INT,
  Operation_Key INT,
  Record_Key INT,
  Part_Key INT
)
INSERT INTO #Action_Table
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN WS.Operation_Key IS NULL THEN 'Delete'
    WHEN WS.Operation_Key IS NOT NULL THEN 'Add'
  END Action,
  CASE
    WHEN WS.Operation_Key IS NULL THEN '0'
    WHEN WS.Operation_Key IS NOT NULL THEN '1'
  END Action_Bit,
  CASE
    WHEN WS.Operation_Key IS NULL THEN WC.Operation_Key
    WHEN WS.Operation_Key IS NOT NULL THEN WS.Operation_Key
  END Operation_Key,
  CASE
    WHEN WS.Operation_Key IS NULL THEN WC.Record_Key
    WHEN WS.Operation_Key IS NOT NULL THEN NULL
  END Workcenter_Component_Key,
  CASE
    WHEN WS.Operation_Key IS NULL THEN WC.Part_Key
    WHEN WS.Operation_Key IS NOT NULL THEN WS.Part_Key
  END Part_Key
FROM #WS_Part_Table WS
FULL OUTER JOIN #WC_Part_Table WC
  ON WC.Part_Key = WS.Part_Key
 AND WC.Operation_Key = WS.Operation_Key
WHERE (WS.Part_Key IS NULL or WC.Part_Key IS NULL) AND (WS.Operation_Key IS NULL or WC.Operation_Key IS NULL)
```

Both the #WS_Part_Table and the #WC_Part_Table are temp tables that I'm constructing using queries, but my dilemma is that I have to **PRE-QUERY** the #WC_Part_Table query on the operation key that I'm interested in, otherwise I get way too many results.

This is the query that I'm using to create the #WC_Part_Table

```
    CREATE TABLE #WC_Part_Table
    (
      Operation_Key INT,
      Record_Key INT,
      Part_Key INT
    )
    -- Workcenter Component Table
    INSERT INTO #WC_Part_Table
    SELECT
      O.Operation_Key,
      WC.Record_Key,
      WC.Part_Key
    FROM Workcenter_Component WC
    JOIN Operation O
      ON O.Default_Workcenter_Key = WC.Workcenter_Key

 /* There is some reason why this next line is needed */
    WHERE O.Operation_Key = 23149
```

Comment: What RDBMS and version are you using?... by the way, do you need a query explicting your action?, can't you just delete or add a row?

Comment: This query is to generate a report to have a human go in and make the edits (long story).  Needless to say I don't have direct access to the database to add/insert/update/delete records, simply query and tell someone else what to do.

Comment: Oh, that's kinda messed up....then you should go with @Cybernate 's answer

Comment: You may find better if you have `WC_Part_Table` and `WS_Part_Table` as `VIEWS` **without** using the `WHERE O.Operation_Key = 23149` condition. Then you can use KenTaylor's or Cybernate's view (where you can add any such condition if you want to manually check and the results are too many).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tyr this to get the results that you have posted:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.Operation_Key, b.Operation_Key) Operation_Key,
             COALESCE(a.Part_Key, b.Part_Key) Part_Key,
             Record_Key,
             CASE 
                WHEN Record_Key IS NULL THEN 'Add'
                ELSE 'Delete'
            END Action
  FROM TableA a FULL OUTER JOIN TableB b
      ON a.Operation_Key = b.Operation_Key
        AND a.Part_Key = b.Part_Key
 WHERE (a.Operation_Key IS NULL) OR (b.Operation_Key IS NULL)
```

**Test Script:**

```
CREATE TABLE #TableA     
(       
    Operation_Key INT,       
    Part_Key INT
) 

INSERT INTO #TableA
SELECT 1,1 
UNION
SELECT 1,2 
UNION
SELECT 2,1 
UNION
SELECT 2,3 

CREATE TABLE #TableB
(       
    Operation_Key INT,       
    Part_Key INT,
    Record_Key INT
) 

INSERT INTO #TableB
SELECT 1,1,1 
UNION
SELECT  2,1,2
UNION
SELECT 2,3,3 
UNION
SELECT 2,4,4 


SELECT  COALESCE(a.Operation_Key, b.Operation_Key) Operation_Key,              
                COALESCE(a.Part_Key, b.Part_Key) Part_Key,              
                Record_Key,              
                CASE                  
                    WHEN Record_Key IS NULL THEN 'Add'                 
                    ELSE 'Delete'             
                END Action   
    FROM    #TableA a FULL OUTER JOIN #TableB b       
        ON  a.Operation_Key = b.Operation_Key         
     AND    a.Part_Key = b.Part_Key  
 WHERE (a.Operation_Key IS NULL) OR (b.Operation_Key IS NULL)
```

**Output:**

```
Operation_Key   Part_Key    Record_Key  Action
1   2   NULL    Add
2   4   4   Delete
```

Comment: Rewrote the query to utilize the **coalesce** function but it still isn't working.  I'm getting all ADD records and no DELETE records.  Plus the ADD records include all records that already exist in the table.

Comment: @NA Slacker: I haved added test script I used to check the query and got the results as needed. Pls chck

Comment: The problem is the "CASE" statement on the Record_Key field; it should be on the field A.Operation_Key or A.Part_Key to assign the "Add" or "Delete" correctly. As written, testing any field on the B table reverses the add and delete. See my answer to this question...

Comment: @Ken: I think Null value for Record_key can be used to identify if the record should be added or removed. I have posted the test script and results which get the desired output.

Comment: @Cybermate: You're correct; I read your logic backwards. :-) Completely depends on which way you test and order the results. I am voting your answer up; I think we posted simultaneously the first time.

Comment: Yep, your test scrip does return exactly what I'm looking forward.  See my comment below, I think that there is something else in my data that I'm not aware of that is giving me the extra results.  I'm going to keep digging.

Comment: @NA Slacker: See if you can isolate a few (real) records that are giving you the unexpected results and post those for us to take a look at....

Comment: @NA Slacker: Can you post the code for `WS_Part_Table` as well? It might be relevant.

Comment: I think I have found the source of my issue.  My query is getting killed due to a behind the scenes row count cap when building one of my original TEMP tables.  There is unfortunately zero error results to tell me that is what is happening.  So I need to attack the problem from a different angle.

Comment: @NA Slacker: Don't use temp tables and inserts, use Views.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm limited in what I can do.  I don't actually have full access to this particular database.  If it can't be solved with temp tables, CTE's, or derived tables then I'm sort of sunk.

Answer (score 2):

Add to B:

```
insert into B (Operation_Key, Part_Key, Record_Key)
values
select Operation_Key, Part_Key, null as Record_Key from A
left join b on a.Operation_Key = b.Operation_Key and
a.Part_Key = b.Part_Key
where b.Part_Key is null
```

Delete from B:

```
Delete from B
select * from B left join A on b.Operation_Key = a.Operation_Key and
    b.Part_Key = a.Part_Key
where a.Operation_Key is null
```

Comment: I think he's looking to generate a table of "soft inserts" or "soft deletes". Your queries should do the trick, he could just UNION them together and add the "Add" or "Delete" columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can get exactly the results table you want (looking at your example set up) by making clever use of the SQL "COALESCE" operator.  If you use a query like this:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(A.Operation_Key, B.Operation_Key) as Operation_Key,
    COALESCE(A.part_key, B.part_key) as Part_Key,
    B.Record_Key,
    CASE WHEN A.Operation_Key IS NULL THEN
        'Delete'
    ELSE
        'Add'
    END AS [Action] FROM A
FULL OUTER JOIN B 
    ON A.Operation_Key = B.Operation_Key 
        AND A.Part_Key= B.Part_Key
WHERE A.Operation_Key IS NULL 
    OR B.Operation_Key IS NULL
```

...you'll get a result table exactly like your example.

Comment: There must be something else going in the data then that I haven't been able to identify because as soon as I pre-filter the one data table I'm able to get the results I want using both my original query and the **coalesce** function.

Comment: @NA Slacker: What do you mean by pre filter the data table. Can you pls elaborate?

Comment: @NA Slacker: Does the fields PART_KEY and OPERATION_KEY already have nulls in the data?

Comment: It shouldn't, but that's what I'm thinking might be the case.  I'm going to spend some time digging in to this.  Thanks for all the help.  I know I'm close.